# rich:scrollableDataTable is generating an extra column

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, jboss7.x, ajax4jsf

I am using the following code:

```
<rich:scrollableDataTable value="#{allActiveUsers}" 
                                    var="user" 
                                    rows="20"
                                    >
                         <a4j:support event="onRowClick" 
                                      action="#{editUser.prepareSelectionOfUser(user)}"
                                      reRender="editUserForm"
                                      />   

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Active  Users" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:column>

                            <f:facet name="header">Username</f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.login}" />
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">Full Name</f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">Email address</f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.email}" />
                        </h:column>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <rich:datascroller renderIfSinglePage="false" maxPages="5" />
                    </f:facet>

                </rich:scrollableDataTable>
```

The problem is that it is producing a white ghost column without any reason. Does anyone know how I can get rid of it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the richfaces forum:

> This column is used to fill table space when overall width of columns is not enough to cover table space. When columns are resized, they are taking space from this extra column.

According to [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/150502) on the richfaces forum, it's by design. And it occurs to compensate for table/column resizing during scrolling. To fix, manually set the `width` attribute on the columns.

See also [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/message/50683)